# Detect property of the transition end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I sought to detect the property of which the transition is completed in the case of several transitions of the same element with different delay, like:

```js
var cssTransitionEnd = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend';
$('div').on(cssTransitionEnd, function(e) {
  var borderColorEnd, backgroundColorEnd;
  
  // Detect if this is border or background who ended ?
  
  if(borderColorEnd) {
    
  }
  if(backgroundColorEnd) {
    
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
  transition: border-color 1s, background-color 2s;
}
div:hover {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `propertyName` property that comes with the [`transtionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event to find the name of the property whose `transition` has ended.

One thing to note with this property is that it will not return the shorthand property names. Instead it will return the following longhand names for the `border-color` property:

- `border-left-color`
- `border-right-color`
- `border-top-color`
- `border-bottom-color`

**Note:** For some reason, accessing the `propertyName` property of the JS event object does not seem to work on Firefox (but works on Chrome). Using jQuery's event object instead of it seems to work as expected. Can only assume that there is some browser inconsistencies that jQuery does a good job of solving for us.

```js
var cssTransitionEnd = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend';
$('div').on(cssTransitionEnd, function(event) {

  /* Just to make the output obvious :) */
  $('div').html($('div').html() + event.originalEvent.propertyName + '<br>');

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
  transition: border-color 1s, background-color 2s;
}
div:hover {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Looking good, just test on chrome and rok, but not on Firefox http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/aOXede

Comment: Oh sorry @Pik_at, I am not able to test in Firefox at the moment but I expected it to work because my reference was from MDN. Let me see if I can find any info.

Comment: @Pik_at: I just verified in a old FF version (and also checked with a couple of fellow users on chat) and it doesn't seem to work. I will update the answer when I find more info about it.

Comment: @Pik_at: It seems like there are some browser inconsistencies with this and accessing the propertyName through jQuery's event object seems to work.